# How to change JQuery Datepicker Months and Years display to Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

I have just started working on a Calendar Project in `JQuery` where I can choose appointments in an event, and **I would like to change the current years and months choosing menu from the current form to a dropdown choosing menu** because I want to make it easier to switch between dates so that I can find the desired appointments.

example of what would I like to achieve:
[image]

My question is how could I change it?

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}


.popover
{
  left: 5% !important;
  top: 120% !important;
}


.btn 
{
    margin: 1%;
}


#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


.popover button{
  background: #f48024;
}

.popover button:hover{
  background:#fcb67c;
}

.popover button:focus{
  background: #052049;
}

.popover button:focus:active{
  background: #052049;
}

.arrow {
  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #dad55e;
  background: #fffa90;
  color: #777620;
}





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <div  class="date-picker-2" placeholder="Recipient's username" id="ttry" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></div>
      <span class="" id="example-popover-2"></span> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-content" class="hidden"> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-title" class="hidden"> </div>

<script>

$('.date-picker-2').popover({
    html : true, 
    
    content: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-title").html();
    }

});

$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
 minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText) { 
        $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Available Appointments</b>');
        var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
        $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Available times <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
        $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
    }
});

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to the date picker the following lines:
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,

```
$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
     minDate: new Date(),
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText) { 
            $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Available Appointments</b>');
            var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
            $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Available times <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
            $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
        }
    });
```